# HTML inside mini-pager navigation control labels

Tags: views, theming, paging

I'm trying to customize the output of the mini-pager controller (the "next" and "previous" link with arrows) in a view.
Actually, it is possible to insert custom text for "previous"-link in the view pager options, in the "tag" section.
I tried to add inside the form (for a test), this:

```
<i class="icon-chevron-left"></i>
```

The resulting output is

```
<a href="front?page=1">&lt;i class="icon-chevron-right"&gt;&lt;/i&gt;</a>
```

So actually I think it filters HTML.
Do you think it's possible to include HTML?

Answer (score 1):

I just spent the last 2 hours trying to solve the same problem, using many different approaches, but I finally managed to get it right.

You just have to override the [theme_pager_link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!pager.inc/function/theme_pager_link/7) function in your theme by copying the code content to template.php and change the return (last line), removing the **check_plain()** function of the **$text** variable, leaving it like:

```
return '<a' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>' . $text . '</a>';
```